# Putting text from txt file into linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, stringtokenizer

I'm trying to tokenize lines of numeric expressions into a linked list for a CS Project.  I have to use my own Linked List that I created in a previous lab.

I tokenize each number and operator of a line, and insert each token into a node in my linked list as they are tokenized.  When I code the program to print out each token as it's tokenized, each token is printed.  But when I tell it to print out the linked list that contains each token as a node, some operators are missing.  I don't know what is the cause for this behavior.

Below is the method that creates the Linked List containing each token:

```
    public static LinkedListTest ReadInFile(String path){
    File file = new File(path);
    LinkedListTest list = new LinkedListTest();

    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        int count = 0;

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()){
                list.insert(st.nextToken());
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Below are the methods for inserting into a linked list and printing one:

```
public class LinkedListTest implements LinkedList {
private Node head;

public LinkedListTest(){
    head = new Node();
}

public void insert(Object x){
    if (lookup(x) == false){

        if (head.data == null)
            head.data = x;

        else{
        /*
        Node NewNode = new Node();
        NewNode.data = x;
        NewNode.next = head;
        head = NewNode;
        */

            //InsertLast
            Node temp = head;

            while (temp.next != null){
                temp = temp.next;
            }

            Node NewNode = new Node();
            NewNode.data = x;
            NewNode.next = null;

            temp.next = NewNode;

        }
    }
}

public void printList(){
    Node temp = head;

    while (temp.next != null){
        System.out.print(temp.data + " ");
        temp = temp.next;
    }

    System.out.print(temp.data + " ");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.  The lookup clause on my insert function was screwing it up.